# Replacing character in a list with keys from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python

I have a dictionary containing lists like

```
char_code = {'1':['b','f','v','p'],'2':['c','g','j','k','q','s','x','z'], '3':['d','t'], '4':['l'],'5':['m','n'], '6':['r']}
```

I have another list containing characters

```
word_list = ['r', 'v', 'p', 'c']
```

I want to replace the letters in word_list with keys in the dictionary so that it should become

```
['6', '1', '1', '2']
```

I tried some thing like

```
word_list[:]=[char_code.get(e,'') for e in word_list]
```

Comment: what you've tried?

Comment: In your own words: when you create the `word_list`, which way do you want the logic to work: do you take a value like `'r'` and look up the corresponding `'1'`? Or do you take `'1'` and look up `'r'`? Therefore, which makes more sense to use as the *key* for a lookup dictionary? Does this give you an idea how to start solving the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [invert the dictionary](/questions/483666), so that you can easily look up the digit symbol for a given letter:

```
num_code = {
    letter: digit
    for digit, letters in char_code.items()
    for letter in letters
}
```

Then simply [use that lookup to do the mapping](/questions/25082410/):

```
word_list[:] = [num_code[letter] for letter in word_list]
```

Which gives us the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with `for` looping on **word_list** and using `list comprehension` to find each list element inside **char_code**`dictionary and finally`append` the keys like this-

```
char_code = {'1':['b','f','v','p'],'2':['c','g','j','k','q','s','x','z'], '3':['d','t'], '4':['l'],'5':['m','n'], '6':['r']}

word_list = ['r', 'v', 'p', 'c']
expected_list = []
for word in word_list:
    expected_list.append([k for k, v in char_code.items() if word in v][0])
print(expected_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['6', '1', '1', '2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary isn't structured efficiently to do the kind of lookup you're asking for - it's "inside out". You *can* do it, but it's clumsy. You want the key to be a letter and it's value to be the code, but you have the other way around.

Transform your dictionary and it will simplify your list creation:

```py
>>> letter_to_code = {letter: code for code, lst in char_code.items() for letter in lst}
>>> [letter_to_code[letter] for letter in word_list]
['6', '1', '1', '2']
```

Comment: I think you'll find that I beat you to it with this approach :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not a very constructive (or accurate) comment...

Comment: How isn't it accurate? I use the same techniques for both inverting the dictionary and for using the dictionary to map onto the input list; and I posted my answer first. The only thing different (aside from naming) is that I slice-assign back to the original list, because OP's attempt did that.